# Recuperar ID maior em consulta no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

tudo bem?

Estou trabalhando em um site de um cliente, que foi desenvolvido utilizando codeigniter. As tabelas criadas pelo programador, não foram projetadas para algumas funções, e o cliente solicitou que eu as criasse.

Tenho uma tabela de serviços, e uma de histórico de serviços, e a cada vez que um serviço é atualizado, essa tabela recebe um novo registro vinculado ao serviço realizado. Eu precisaria retornar o último ID do histórico vinculado ao serviço em questão. E gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso.

Pra melhor entendimento, aqui estão outras informações.

Tabela de Serviços

[image: Tabela de Serviços]

Histórico de Serviços

[image: Tabela de Histórico de Serviços]

A tabela de Histórico de Serviços, tem na coluna "id_servico", a identificação do serviço que está vinculada à outra tabela. Eu preciso retornar da tabela de histórico, o ID mais recente vinculado ao serviço em questão. Nesse caso do exemplo acima, deveria retornar os IDs "1002" e "1004", mas está retornando o "1000" e o "1003".

Esse é o código que estou usando pra listar:

Função no Model

```
function busca_historico() {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, 'DESC');
        $this->db->group_by('id_servico');
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tabela);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Função no Controller

```
function teste(){

        $data['servico'] = $this->servicos_model->get_result();
        $data['historico'] = $this->historico_servicos->get_historico();

        $this->load->view('teste/teste', $data);

    }
```

Código na View

```
    <?php foreach($historico as $val) : ?>

        <?php if($val->status == 'Concluído') : ?>

             <?= $val->id; ?>

             <br />

        <?php endif; ?>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Bom, é isso. Não sei o que me falta pra fazer funcionar. Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: se os valor de ID são sequenciais, e como não vi um campo data na sua tabela, pode pegar o maior ID (`select max(ID) where id_servico=533`), usei 533 como exemplo

Comment: Existe um campo "data" na tabela, mas está formatado como CHAR e isso acabou me complicando. Daí fiquei com esse problema. Sei que existem maneiras de contornar isso, mas todas as que encontrei envolvem executar queries direto na tabela pra depois converter de CHAR pra DATE, e como há o risco de zerar os dados da coluna, estou tentando encontrar uma maneira alternativa. Vou tentar essa sua dica.